# Is there a way to inform classifiers in R of the relative costs of misclassification?

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, cost-based-optimizer

This is a general question.  Are there classifiers in R -- functions that perform classification implementing classification algorithms-- that accept as input argument the relative cost of misclassification. E.g. if a misclassification of a positive to negative has cost 1 the opposite has cost 3.

If yes which are these functions?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. If you are using the [caret](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/caret/caret.pdf) package (you should; it provides 'standardization' for 200+ classification and regression methods by wrapping almost all relevant R's packages), you can set the *weights* argument of the *train* function (see p.152; see also [here](https://www.r-bloggers.com/handling-class-imbalance-with-r-and-caret-an-introduction/)) for models that support class weights. [This answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/162297/class-weights-in-caret) lists some of the models that support class weights.